# Why does this code work only after running the app for the second time?

Tags: android, sqlite

What this activity does is copy the database from the assets folder to the applications database folder , if the app is running for the first. But the database is only copied after the app is run for the second time!

```
package fifth3.sem;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Splash extends Activity {
static DBAdapter db;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String destPath="/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/cryptdb2zx";
    File f=new File(destPath);
    File f2=new File("emptyfile");
    if(!f2.exists()){
        //do nothing
    {
        try {
            Log.w("akash", "file does not exist");
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("cryptdb2"),new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            f2.createNewFile();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    } 
    db=new DBAdapter(this); 
    db.open();

    Thread t=new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            try{
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
            finally{
                startActivity(new Intent("login.screen"));
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();

}
public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream,OutputStream outputStream)throws IOException{
    Log.w("akash", "copying");
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length=inputStream.read(buffer))>0){
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
    Log.w("akash", "copied");
}
```

}

Comment: also, the database is being overwritten every time the app is restarted

Comment: whats the meaning of doing   for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } ? Just do Thread.sleep(5*1000);

Comment: thank you. but i dont think that solved my problem .

Comment: is there an else statement coupled with your " if(!f2.exists()){" ? You have a set of extra brackets in there that serve no purpose so I'm wondering if you deleted the else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your database adapter, I can't be certain, however likely it doesn't work the first time because you try to copy the db before the directory exists.
Normally, the database adapter will create a database if it doesn't exist. This will create the 'databases' directory. Thus, when you open the newly installed app, the directory doesn't exist and the copying fails. However, immediately after the copy logic, you create a db adapter and it (probably) creates the db (and directory containing it.) Hence, the second time you run, the copying is successful.

This should run as you would like (the ordering is what is important):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db=new DBAdapter(this); 
    db.open();

    String destPath="/data/data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/cryptdb2zx";
    File f=new File(destPath);
    File f2=new File("emptyfile");
    if(!f2.exists()){
        //do nothing
    {
        try {
            Log.w("akash", "file does not exist");
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("cryptdb2"),new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            f2.createNewFile();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    } 

}
```